# Reliable convert strings to doubles and back

Tags: c++, string, double, string-parsing

I was searching for functions to reliably convert strings to doubles and then back to strings in c++, so that the output string is exactly the same as the input string. But I could not find reliable functions even after hours of searching and trying out.

To check if the functions are reliable I made the following test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string double2string(double value){
    //...
}
double string2double(string value){
    //...
}


int main(){

    string strings[] = {
        "111111111111110000",
        "11111111111111000",
        "1111111111111100",
        "111111111111110",
        "11111111111111",
        "1111111111111.1",
        "111111111111.11",
        "11111111111.111",
        "1111111111.1111",
        "111111111.11111",
        "11111111.111111",
        "1111111.1111111",
        "111111.11111111",
        "11111.111111111",
        "1111.1111111111",
        "111.11111111111",
        "11.111111111111",
        "1.1111111111111",
        "0.11111111111111",
        "0.011111111111111",
        "0.0011111111111111",
        "0.00011111111111111"
    };
    double doubles[] = {
        111111111111110000,
        11111111111111000,
        1111111111111100,
        111111111111110,
        11111111111111,
        1111111111111.1,
        111111111111.11,
        11111111111.111,
        1111111111.1111,
        111111111.11111,
        11111111.111111,
        1111111.1111111,
        111111.11111111,
        11111.111111111,
        1111.1111111111,
        111.11111111111,
        11.111111111111,
        1.1111111111111,
        0.11111111111111,
        0.011111111111111,
        0.0011111111111111,
        0.00011111111111111
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < 22; i++){
        cout 
            << (string2double(strings[i])==doubles[i])
            << " " 
            << (double2string(doubles[i])==strings[i])
            << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

"Why this test?", you might ask. Let me explain:
A c++ double has 52 bits to hold an integer number. The highest this number can get is 2^52-1, or 4503599627370495. This number is 16 digits long. But since not all 16-digit-long numbers would fit into those bits whithout an overflow, my requirement was to reliably convert only all numbers that are 15 digits long.  Leading or trailing zeroes don't count, since they are representable with the 11 exponent bits.

So, basically, I ensured that all those numbers should theoretically fit into a double, without any overflows, so that I can convert them 1:1 back to strings.

Now: Do you know of any functions to convert from double to string and back that can fullfill the test with only "1"s printed out?

Comment: Your test is based on the flawed assumption that, for example, `X.1` can be represented as a double in the first place (it can't). If you *started* with a double, converted it to a string, printed the string, then converted back to a double, you'd find that it round-trips as you expect. But not every number is actually representable as a double in the first place. Basically, no matter how much precision you had, there are some numbers that simply cannot be represented in base-2 exponential notation, which is how floating point numbers are encoded.

Comment: They don't "theoretically fit into a double". None of the fractional values can be represented exactly by a binary floating-point format. If you need to represent non-integer decimal numbers exactly, you'll need a different representation.

Comment: @tgmath brings up a *very* good point. Unless you're assigning to a double literal, the odds of any two doubles comparing via `==` is astronomically low, thanks to the aforementioned numeric instability inherent in doubles. This is why, for exmaple, `for(double i=0.0;i!=1.0;i+=0.1)` will *never* terminate.

Comment: @aruisdante & Mike Seymour Damn, really?? My whole life is a lie :D Would you maybe be so kind to explain me why those numbers don't fit into a double?

Comment: Don't compare floating decimal numbers like this `string2double(strings[i])==doubles[i]`. (Sorry for deleting the comment earlier.)

Comment: @VanCoding The number `0.1` (base 10) is `0.00011001100110011...` in base 2, thus, an infinite representation as binary. The type double can only get close. E.g. if you store `0.00011` as binary it corresonds to `0.0975` in decimal.

Comment: There are many documents you can read, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) [are](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/281429/filename/floating-point-article.pdf) a [few](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) [examples](http://ta.twi.tudelft.nl/users/vuik/wi211/disasters.html). The basic problem comes from the fact that IEEE floating point represents numbers in a [base-2 exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) format, which limits the number of values in base 10 that are actually encodable.

Comment: This is also why you *never* represent money in floating point. You always use a 'money class' that uses integer representations, preferably of infinite precision. Doing anything else will 100% result in incorrect calculations and could get you into a *lot* of trouble.

Comment: Ok, interesting, I did this test with JavaScript and it managed to pass the test without any problems. It seems that JavaScript's double implementation works different. Anyway, is there maybe a library that can emulate the expected behavior?

Comment: @aruisdante What's strange: This Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format states that "If a decimal string with at most 15 significant digits is converted to IEEE 754 double precision representation and then converted back to a string with the same number of significant digits, then the final string should match the original." Isn't C++ using IEEE 754 doubles?

Comment: @aruisdante Don't all of my numbers have 14 significant digits? Oh, no, the first 4 and the last 4 have more, right?

Comment: Well, so is really the text wrong? Because it clearly states that all decimal values with at most 15 significant digits should be converted flawlessly... That would be enough for me.

Comment: See @JamesKanze's answer below. Doing some simple testing, it looks like if you use ``std::stringstream`` to do your conversions, you should be able to round-trip even unrepresentable 15 digit numbers. Note that it's definitely approximating, so if you try and use your `0.1` value in actual math, it may not do what you expect.

Comment: C++ isn't *guaranteed* to use IEEE 754 doubles, but most implementations you'll encounter probably do. And it has 53 bits, not 52, since there's an implied `1` to the left of the 52 bits.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically impossible.  There are too many ways to specify
a double in text format, and information about this format is
lost once you convert to double.  On my machine, for example,
all of the following strings convert to the same double:

```
1
1.0
1e0
1.000000000000000000001
+1.0
0001.0
```

and many more.  This information is defitively lost once you
have the double.

If you restrict your input to a specific format, say scientific
with exactly 15 digits total, then anything up to 15 digits
should round trip correctly if your machine uses IEEE.

Comment: I'm only interested in the outwritten representation. It's not a requirement that it can read `1e0`, but if it should be able to do so, it should be converted back to `1`. Basically i want the most compact version, without using `e`, which means stripping away leading and trailing zeroes, if they are not needed.

Comment: Yeah, then [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) is probably what you are looking for. You can ``ss << double`` to convert to string, then ``ss >> double`` to convert back again. You can adjust the behavior, but the default is decimal-notation with no leading/trailing zeros (except a single leading zero for ``-1.0 < x < 1.0``). And it should round-trip as you expect.

Comment: @arusidante when converting to string using stringstream, it only goes up to 6 digits after comma. So, 0.1111111 will get converted "0.111111", missing one comma. Also it adds unwanted e+xxx syntax to the numbers. Any workaraund?

Comment: @aruisdante The default is _not_ fixed (which is what I presume you meant by decimal), but depends on the value (i.e. 1e100 will not generate 100 digits, a decimal, and then a few more, but will use scientific notation).  But it is designed to result in the smallest representation, at least most of the time.

Comment: @VanCoding You specify the precision.  Specify 15 if you want to be sure that all possible strings of that precision will result in different `double` values (but not all `double` values will result in a unique string); specify 17 if you want all possible `double` values to have a unique string (but there will be several different strings of that format which will result in the same `double` value).

Comment: @VanCoding What do you mean by noise?

Comment: @VanCoding You'd have to give a very concrete example to show what you're doing, and what you're getting.  Visual C++ works, at least for this, and has worked for the longest time.

Comment: @VanCoding they're not random, they're a direct consequence of binary numbers not being able to represent decimal numbers exactly. That's not the case in the other direction, binary numbers *can* be represented exactly in decimal if you use enough digits, it's just that those digits aren't likely to be 0. You'll probably need to do your own custom code if you want to round binary numbers to the nearest 15-digit decimal.